# How to write a jest test for the router.listen callback

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, enzyme

How do you go about testing the router.listen callback?

I've got this below code:

```
  if (router) {
    router.listen(() => {
      updatedResource = updateResource(resource, checkedOverrides);
    });
  }
```

I've managed to test the calling of the router.listen method but to get 100% coverage I need to also test if the updateResource method gets called which gets imported into the file as a child export.

`import { updateResource } from 'path'`

I tried to spy on it to see if it got called but this did not work. Below is an example of the test that I have written so far:

```
  it('should call the listen method when router exists.', () => {
    // const mockedUpdateResource = updateResource;
    // console.log(updateResource());

    const router = {
      listen: jest.fn(),
    };

    window.history.pushState({}, '', '/?Colour%20group=White');
    wrapper = shallow(<RangeParent consumer={consumer} resource={WCMSdata} router=    {router} />);

    // const spy = jest.spyOn(updateResource, 'updateResource');
    // window.history.pushState({}, '', '/');
    // const spy = jest.spyOn(updateResource);

    expect(router.listen).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide how the `router` is imported in the code?

Comment: Sure, its `import { withRouter } from 'react-router';`

Comment: withRouter gets used as a HOC and wraps round the component giving router as a prop to the component

Comment: I was wondering if its router.listen or history.listen? what does that listen do?

Comment: Basically it listens for url changes, the project I'm working on is using an older version of Router

Answer (score 0):

You are spying on updateResource, instead spy on path

```
import { updateResource } from 'path'

const mockUpdateResource = jest.spyOn(path, 'updateResource');
```

else try the below,

```
 const listenMock = jest.spyOn(router, 'listen');   
 listenMock.mockReturnValue(jest.fn());
 const listenCallback = listenMock.mock.calls[0][0]; //modify as per cb args 
 listenCallback();
```

or try mocking them,

```
jest.mock('react-router', () => ({
  router: {
     listen: jest.fn(_=>)
  }
}));


jest.mock('path', () => ({
    updateResource: jest.fn()
}))
```